# Complex similar match between number against a list

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

I´d like to get the more similar number within a list of numbers. In column A are some numbers and in column B a related code for that number.
In column C are entries for which I want to find the most similar value and put output in column D showing the related product if possible. I hope make sense.

I show in colors the more similar "Short codes" for each entry.

My humble attempt is like below, I use Index and Match to find exact matches, but for closest matches I don't know how to start.

I like to have this using VBA since I´d apply it to values not in columns, but in an vba array for example.

```
Sub GestClosestMatch()

Set wf = WorksheetFunction

ExactMatch = wf.Index(Range("B2:B15"), Application.Match(Range("C12"), Range("A2:A15"), 0))
ClosestMatch = ?

End Sub
```

I´ve tested the UDF in [this thread](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-find-the-most-similar-word-to-a-word-using-excel-or-vba.1052253/), but shows me `#NAME?` error when I try it.

This is how it looks the data for easy understanding

[image]

The input data is below:

```
+------------+---------+-----------+
| SHORT CODE | PRODUCT | ENTRIES   |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 237        | CMR     | 18763044  |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 230        | MUS     | 187635    |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 61         | APS     | 23092     |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 31         | NLW     | 3162      |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 599        | ANT     | 38050     |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 358        | FIY     | 33        |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 33751      | FRJ     | 49185     |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 65         | SGP     | 51078     |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 1721       | SXM     | 1246      |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 1876       | QAM     | 389094702 |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 81         | JHN     | 38909     |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 124622     | BRB     | 4475      |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 38909      | PUK     |           |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| 3890947021 | JIM     |           |
+------------+---------+-----------+
```

**UPDATE**

If I load the data in arrays previously like this:

```
Sub DataStoredInArrays()
Dim CodesArr(1 To 14, 1 To 2)
Dim EntriesArr(1 To 12, 1 To 3)

For i = 1 To 14
    For j = 1 To 2
        CodesArr(i, j) = Cells(i + 1, j)
    Next
Next

For i = 1 To 12
        EntriesArr(i, 1) = "X"
        EntriesArr(i, 2) = Cells(i + 1, "C")
        EntriesArr(i, 3) = Cells(i + 1, "D")
Next

End Sub
```

And the structure of the arrays would be like this, having the output in 3rd "column" of `EntriesArr` :
[image]

Comment: Looks like you intend for the numbers to be treated as strings for comparison? And what determines "NOT FOUND"? Fuzzy matching below a certain percentage?

Comment: Do columns `A` and `C` contain values or formulas? Is the result supposed to be a 2D one-based two-column array with `Entries` and matching `Related Products`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 A, B and C are only values. The result would be only one column, this is "Related Products"

Comment: @QHarr Yes, I think to be compared the numbers should be treated as strings. Not found values are for example 4475 because in column A there is any value that begins with  447, 4475, 4475XYZ. In the case for 38050 there is any value beginning with 380XXX. There is 38909 but at least 3 numbers should be used to compared. For example 380 would be a match for 38050 and 3805, 38050, 38050XXX. That would be a "rule" for minimum matching (at least 3) for maximum matching would be the value that matches better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

'finds the first instance of string in a range
Function FindLongestMatch(srcArray As Range, valueToFind As Range) As Variant

    Dim c As Range, a1 As Integer, a2 As Integer
    Dim retVal As Variant
    
    retVal = ""
    
    If Trim(valueToFind) = "" Then GoTo Exit_FindLongestMatch
    
    For Each c In srcArray
        a1 = InStr(1, valueToFind, c.Value, vbTextCompare)
        a2 = InStr(1, c.Value, valueToFind, vbTextCompare)
        If a1 > 0 Or a2 > 0 Then
            retVal = c.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c


Exit_FindLongestMatch:
    FindLongestMatch = retVal

End Function
```

Then, in column `D` add the following formula; `=FindLongestMatch($A$2:$A$15;$C2)` and fill down to the last row in a range.

Note: replace `;` with `,` when needed.

This should return:

[image]

Now, you're able to use `VLookup` formula in column `E` ;)

Feel free to improve above function to your needs. For example, if you replace

```
retVal = c.Value
```

with

```
retVal = c.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value
```

you'll get a Product name.

**[EDIT]**

Improved version - accordingly to the OP's comments. Note: you can NOT use `Range.Offset()` function in below code. You have to use `VLookup` function in another column.

```
'finds the best match
Function FindLongestMatch(srcArray As Range, valueToFind As Range) As Variant

    Dim c As Range, a1 As Integer, a2 As Integer
    Dim retVal As Variant
    
    retVal = ""
    
    If Trim(valueToFind) = "" Then GoTo Exit_FindLongestMatch
    
    For Each c In srcArray
        a1 = InStr(1, valueToFind, c.Value, vbTextCompare)
        a2 = InStr(1, c.Value, valueToFind, vbTextCompare)
        If a1 > 0 Or a2 > 0 Then
            If Len(Left(c.Value, Len(valueToFind))) > Len(retVal) Then retVal = c.Value
        End If
    Next c


Exit_FindLongestMatch:
    FindLongestMatch = retVal

End Function
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help. It seems to work with the sample input. I'll try it with a kind of large input. If values in column A  an B would be stored in a 2D array and values in column C would be stored in another array, would work only changing the type of variables from "as range" to "as variant"?

Comment: What variables you want to change? Function input variables?

Comment: Well, above code is Excel specfic solution. So, if you would like to operate on arrays, you'll need to make several changes.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've tested and shows correct output but when I change retVal to `retVal = c.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value` the last 2 values in output are wrong. Is strange.

Comment: Not really... Take a deep look at my code. Then you'll understand why `Offset()` function is not allowed this time.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check to try to understand your logic in this code.

Answer (score 1):

### Two Directional Partial Match

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub matchValues()
    Const ProcName As String = "matchValues"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A2"
    Const sColOffset As Long = 1
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const lFirst As String = "C2"
    Const dColOffset As Long = 1
    Const NF As String = "NOT FOUND"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim doExit As Boolean
    
    ' Source
    
    ' Define Source Lookup (Column) Range.
    Set rg = refColumn(wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst))
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        doExit = True
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    ' Write values from Source Lookup Range to Source Lookup Array.
    Dim sLookup As Variant: sLookup = getColumnFormula(rg)
    ' Write values from Source Data Range to Source Data Array.
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = getColumn(rg.Offset(, sColOffset))
    ' Determine Source Rows Count.
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(sLookup, 1)
    
    ' Destination
    
    ' Define Destination Lookup (Column) Range.
    Set rg = Nothing
    Set rg = refColumn(wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(lFirst))
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        doExit = True
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    ' Write values from Destination Lookup Range to Destination Lookup Array.
    Dim dLookup As Variant: dLookup = getColumnFormula(rg)
    ' Determine Destination Rows Count.
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = UBound(dLookup, 1)
    ' Define Destination Data (Column) Range.
    Set rg = rg.Offset(, dColOffset)
    ' Define Destination Data Array.
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Loop
    
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim cMatch As Variant
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    For i = 1 To drCount
        cValue = dLookup(i, 1)
        If Not IsError(cValue) Then
            If Len(cValue) > 0 Then
                cMatch = Application.Match(cValue & "*", sLookup, 0)
                If IsNumeric(cMatch) Then
                    dData(i, 1) = sData(cMatch, 1)
                Else
                    For k = 1 To srCount
                        If LCase(cValue) Like LCase(sLookup(k, 1)) & "*" Then
                            dData(i, 1) = sData(k, 1)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next k
                    If k > srCount Then
                        dData(i, 1) = NF
                    End If
                End If
            Else ' Len(cValue) = 0 (e.g. 'Empty', "'", =""...)
            End If
        Else ' 'cValue' contains an error value.
        End If
    Next i
    
    rg.Value = dData
    
ProcExit:
    If doExit = True Then
        MsgBox "Could not do it.", vbCritical, "Fail"
    Else
        MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
    End If
        
    Exit Sub
clearError:
    doExit = True
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

Function refColumn( _
    FirstCellRange As Range, _
    Optional ByVal NonBlankInsteadOfNonEmpty As Boolean = False) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "refColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not FirstCellRange Is Nothing Then
        With FirstCellRange.Cells(1)
            Dim cLookIn As XlFindLookIn
            If NonBlankInsteadOfNonEmpty Then
                cLookIn = xlValues
            Else
                cLookIn = xlFormulas
            End If
            Dim cel As Range
            Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                .Find("*", , cLookIn, , , xlPrevious)
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                Set refColumn = .Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1)
            End If
        End With
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Function getColumn( _
    rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnNumber As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal doTranspose As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "getColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        If ColumnNumber > 0 And ColumnNumber <= rg.Columns.Count Then
            With rg.Columns(ColumnNumber)
                Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
                Dim Result As Variant
                If rCount > 1 Then
                    If doTranspose Then
                        Dim Data As Variant: Data = .Value
                        ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To rCount)
                        Dim r As Long
                        For r = 1 To rCount
                            Result(1, r) = Data(r, 1)
                        Next r
                        getColumn = Result
                    Else
                        getColumn = .Value
                    End If
                Else
                    ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Result(1, 1) = .Value
                    getColumn = Result
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Function getColumnFormula( _
    rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnNumber As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal doTranspose As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "getColumnFormula"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        If ColumnNumber > 0 And ColumnNumber <= rg.Columns.Count Then
            With rg.Columns(ColumnNumber)
                Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
                Dim Result As Variant
                If rCount > 1 Then
                    If doTranspose Then
                        Dim Data As Variant: Data = .Formula
                        ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To rCount)
                        Dim r As Long
                        For r = 1 To rCount
                            Result(1, r) = Data(r, 1)
                        Next r
                        getColumnFormula = Result
                    Else
                        getColumnFormula = .Formula
                    End If
                Else
                    ReDim Result(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Result(1, 1) = .Formula
                    getColumnFormula = Result
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: It gives me `JIM`. Are you sure you're commenting on the right answer? Take a look at (download) my [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WumByIRqZm9xbPEiBPGXXKfKJrsw_emD/view?usp=sharing) on `Google Drive`.

Comment: You're rigth. I was confused. Your output is correct! Would be to much to adapt in order to use your code taking the input stored in an array adding the output in another "column" within same array instead to take input from a range and put output in a range?

Comment: If you take a closer look at the code, you will see that I have named various 'items', e.g. there is the `Source Range` that consists of the `Lookup Column` and the `Data Column` and there is `Destination Range` which also consists of the same columns (`Data Column` is empty initially). Similarly, I have named the arrays. If you can use those words, I'm sure we can understand each other. Also, describe the array (1D or 2D, 0-based or 1-based, which columns...). You could maybe start with something like this: what if instead in the `D. Lookup Column`, the data was in a 2-column 1-based array...

Comment: I've updated my question. Below `UPDATE` you can see if I use that code to store in array CodesArr the Column A and B and have entries in EntriesArr  they will have the structure in image. CodesArr would be of size multiple lines X 2 columns (1 to N, 1 to 2) and EntriesArr would have a size of (1 to N, 1 to 3). In first "Column" of EntriesArr I have some information, in "column 2" I have the `entries` and in "column 3" would go the output. I hope make sense. Thanks again for the help.